# Auto Incrementing natural keys with django / postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Let me preface this in saying that I'm a UI dev who's trying to branch out into more backend coding, so excuse me if my verbiage is off at all.  This is could be a duplicate, but i'm not sure what on god's good green earth i'm even supposed to call what i want to do.

---

Basically, I have categories, and images.  I need to label each image with an acronym of the category it belongs to, and increment a sku after.

*For Example, the following images would be automatically labeled like...*

```
ABC-1
ABC-2
DEF-1
DEF-2
DEF-3
ABC-3*
```

***note**: I want it to increment the ID based on the category, not the total # of images

How would I achieve this in idiomatic Django?

## Models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    abbv        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    urlified    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    hidden      = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Photo(models.Model):
    group       = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pub_date',)
```

Comment: Have you written your models? Do you want to perform this as a once-off script for renaming existing categories/images or do you want to create a form that allows users to create categories/images and have them automatically renamed? Normally each object you create is automatically assigned a primary key which is self incrementing so you can use that when creating your labels.

Comment: the second, let me post the model, wasn't sure how relevant that was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want true composed primary keys, you might want to use [django-compositepks](https://github.com/dcramer/django-compositepks), but that is not ideal.  You might be better off breaking DRY and recording the number (see the category_auto_key field and default).

Transactions will solve it this way:

```
from django.db import transaction

class Group(models.model):
    # your fields
    img_count = models.IntegerField()

    @transaction.atomic
    def next_sku(self):
        self.img_count += 1
        self.save()
        return self.img_count

class Photo(models.Model):
    # your fields
    category_auto_key = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

    def category_image(self):
        return self.group.abbv+"-"+str(self.category_auto_key)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.category_auto_key:
            self.category_auto_key = self.group.next_sku()
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When you need this in your templates, just enclose it in double brackets:

```
{{ photo.category_image }}
```

Comment: damn, is it seriously that easy?

Comment: wait, wont the PK increment based on how many total images there are in the db, not how many there are in the category?

e.g. `abc-1, def-2, abc-3, def-4`

Comment: The more time consuming part is creating the View and the Form you are going to need to provide the user with an interface for uploading images. After that, changing the filename/adding a label as you've outlined is quite straightforward as @Beltiras has outlined

Comment: This increments the counter for every product, yes.  If you want a joined key of category-photo, that is a little more involved (but doable).  Is this a solution or do you want something more detailed?

Comment: BOOM! thats the word i think i needed, a joined key.

Comment: A joined key is a hassle in Django, [django-compositepks](https://github.com/dcramer/django-compositepks) is a solution, but you might be better off atomically incrementing a counter in the model itself.  I'll try to rustle something up.

Comment: thats what i was kinda afraid of, wouldn't that mean an extra query per image added?

Comment: Queries aren't expensive in Django.  If you are running into performance issues you can always offload stuff from the database into a caching mechanism (redis, memcached), add related lookups to fetch foreign keys in the same query, add indexes etc.

Comment: Edited to reference proper model value there, but this looks really good.  I knew there had to be a simple way to achieve this!

Comment: So, after trying to plug this in... i get self is undefined on `category_count(self.category)` - no biggie, probably just needed to be group, not self.group (or category... poor labeling, sorry).

Comment: NEXT i got an error on this line - return Photo.objects.filter(group=cat).count() - NameError: global name 'Photo' is not defined

Comment: Seems that you may need to pass the Photo Class into the category_count method? Maybe try `category_count(self)` and then query with `self.objects.filter(group=self.group).count()`.

May work, not sure, worth a try (shrug)

Comment: @macguru2000: You are absolutely right.  Amended the answer.

Comment: yup, that is the downfall of using count() here, might be wise to actually count Photo creations somewhere, like in a Group Field or another table.

Comment: I see... if an image is deleted the count will be screwed up.  I wonder if its best to just select the last added image and increment it by one or set it to one if there is none.

Comment: Just recently got introduced to SEQUENCE in postgres.  But you would need a SEQUENCE for each Group.

Comment: That would lead to race conditions.

Comment: I'm starting to think the proper way to handle this is keeping a counter in Group, you can atomically increment that one and get the proper value for yourself back, no race conditions, no messiness.  I'll think about it tonight and amend the answer when I come up with the code.

Comment: I agree with Beltiras, no way around having a separate place to store your abbreviation index.

Comment: now getting this error: `ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda`

Comment: Try using the non lambda syntax from before. Do you remember it?

Comment: I was hoping I could use an F() expression to atomically increment the counter and get the value in one step but no.  From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions):In order to access the new value that has been saved in this way, the object will need to be reloaded.

Comment: I've tested that this code functions as promised with the following caveat: It's very hard to get at the race conditions and produce them.  Worst case: on transaction fail an exception is raised.

Comment: I am curious to see what @DerekAdair comes back with, but the new code looks very promising to me. I especially like that you check to see if `category_auto_key` is set before messing with it. :)

Comment: It's not ideal but it works.  What surprises me most is how lambdas are not registered, it has to be a named external function (no self either .....)

Comment: I have found countless examples of using lambda and self in the default of a field, it would seem this was deprecated at some point.

Comment: Did you manage to make this code work?  It worked with 1.7 on my dev machine.

Comment: Works like a charm - sorry!

Comment: Although, i'm going to have to do somethinng about the race condition as i'd like to upload images in bulk via ajax - you can see the final product [here](https://github.com/derek-adair/mauifloralcom)

Comment: There is no race condition, @transaction.atomic should see to it.  Only thing I am not 100% sure on is if it raises an exception or retries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if you just want to generate and store the acronym and sku in a text field, or if you are trying to create relationships between your image categories?

If the later, I would look for a different approach.

If the former, i would use a customized set or save method (hook?) for your image model. It will need do a small one time lookup to count the number of acronym already existing, but I wouldn't worry about the performance too much.

Wasn't sure how to do this exactly in Django off the top of my head, but it looks like the accepted answer works similarly. Anyways, here is my attempt at setting a Model Field during save. Be warned this in untested.

**After looking into it more I think that Beltiras' solution is better**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    # simple column definitions
    group       = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(max_length=100)

    # new column for storing abbv sku
    category_label = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # save override
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # hopefully only set category_label on first save, not sure this
        # works, open to other ideas
        if (self.pk is None):
            count = Photo.objects.filter(group=self.group).count()
            label = self.group.abbv + '-' + count
            setattr(self, 'category_label', label)

        # call the super class' save method
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, ** kwargs)
```

The part I am least sure about is:

```
count = Photo.objects.filter(group=self.group).count()
```

The idea is to query the photos table for photos in the same group and count them. This may need to be replaced with a direct SQL call or done some other way. Let me know what you find.

Comment: couldn't you do `Photo.objects.filter(group=self.group).count()`?

Comment: probably, assuming that the \_\_unicode\_\_ method works with the filter...that I am unsure of.

Comment: Edited my example based on your comment